# Perl PayPal IPN Listener Returning "500 SSL Handshake Failure" message

Tags: perl, ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn

A perl script that has been running ok for two years just began returning "500 SSL Handshake Failure" errors upon postback of IPN message. My host service supports SHA 256, TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1. I'm using my host service's shared cert.
The code (from PayPal's sample script):

```
# read post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
read (STDIN, $query, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
$query .= '&cmd=_notify-validate';

# post back to PayPal system to validate
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
$req = HTTP::Request->new('POST', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
$req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$req->header(Host => 'www.sandbox.paypal.com');
$req->content($query);
$res = $ua->request($req);

if ($res->is_error) {
 # HTTP error
 $retmsg = "HTTP Error:<br />";
 $retmsg .= $res->status_line();
}
```

...

How do I best troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hard to tell without more details but my guess is that you are using an old version of LWP/IO::Socket::SSL or OpenSSL. It does not matter what your server supports in this case. Please add the versions of the libs with: `perl -MLWP::UserAgent -MIO::Socket::SSL -e 'printf "openssl=%x\nio-ssl=%s\nlwp=%s\nperl=%s\n",Net::SSLeay::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER(),IO::Socket::SSL->VERSION,LWP::UserAgent->VERSION,$^V'`

Comment: @Steffen Thanks much for the suggestion. When I execute this command, I receive the message "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1." I can't see any problem with the syntax. What am I missing?

Comment: for whatever reason cut+paste seems to add some strange characters. Try to use http://pastebin.com/gqjcCvsT

Comment: Tried pastebin - same message. Checked it for non-displayable characters - looks clean. Any other thoughts?

Comment: My guess is that you are using Windows then with their strange ways of escaping on the command line. Use the code in http://pastebin.com/t3ae1dNn then, put it into a file and execute this file with Perl.

Comment: Thanks, received the response:
openssl=1000005f
io-ssl=1.44
lwp=6.02
perl=v5.14.2

Answer (score 1):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.sandbox.paypal.com) the site is TLS 1.2 only, that it it does not accept TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1. And according to your comment you are using OpenSSL version 1.0.0e (1000005f). But this version does not support TLS 1.2 yet because such support was only added with version 1.0.1.

This means that your system is too old to support TLS 1.2. You need to upgrade at least the OpenSSL version but preferable the whole system. Note that it does not help to just install a new version of OpenSSL. Instead you would need to recompile all the modules in Perl which make use of the library, i.e. especially Net::SSLeay in this case.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, for your time and advice.With the understanding that this is a "mission critical" application for my client, I will need to find some solution. Would it make sense to find a web host that provides an up-to-date module library that supports TLS 1.2 (if there exists such a host) and migrate the system, or spend the time, as you suggest, recompiling the necessary modules and referencing them in a local library.

Comment: I don't have experience compiling Perl modules, but am certainly willing to learn - I'm just concerned about the time required for the learning curve, since PayPal is scheduled to make these changes in their production environment soon.

Incidentally, my host provider - iPower - has shown little interest in updating the Perl modules in their library, even when it's been pointed out that some of them are not compliant with new security standards.

Comment: @VanScott: If you are using only shared hosting I doubt that it will be possible to upgrade to a newer OpenSSL version by yourself. If your hoster is unwilling to do this you probably need to change. I cannot give you any recommendations which hoster provides the needed support but any hoster offering recent software should have it because the necessary OpenSSL version 1.0.1 was already released about 4 years ago.

Comment: My host service expressed little interest in updating OpenSSL, so I'll be looking for another service. Thanks for the help!